# Karate Framework json response collapse the fields diff order then expected

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber, karate

Expected Json
{ "Main": [ { "Field1": "", "Field2": "", "Field3": "", "Field4": "", "Field5": "", "Field6": "", "Field7": null, "MainSub1": { "Subhead1": [ { "key": "", "value": "" },  ], "Subhead2": [] },"MainSub2": [ { "Field8": "", "Field9": , "Field10": "", "Field11": "", "Field12": "", "Field13": "", "Field14": "", "Field15": "", "Field16": "", "Field17": , "themeName": , "salutationFlag": "",  "subhead3": [ { "key": "", "value": "" }] } ] } ] }

But via Karate Framework
{"Main":[{"Field5":"","MainSub1":{"Subhead1":[{"value":"","key":""}],"Subhead2":[]},"ManiSub2":[{"Subhead3":[{"value":"","key":""}],"Field17":"","Field7":,"Field14":"","Field15":,"Field8":"","Field13":"","Field16":,"Field10":"","Field9":"","Field6":"","Field11":"","Field12":""}],"Field6":"","Field2":"","Field1":"","Field4":"","Field3":"","Field7":}]}

Answer (score 0):

The field order does not matter for JSON.

If you really want you can convert the `responseBytes` to string and use that, but in my opinion that is a waste of time.

```
* string response = responseBytes
```